Python flask/javascript text parsing has these odd squares?

Ok, so that's the picture. I'm attempting to build a local interface to an llm. I've got it almost completely working at a barebones level, except for these maddening squares that appear in my response! I've tried all sorts of things to remove them, but here's my code as it stands, the relevant portions anyway:
def chat():
    data = request.json
    query = data.get('message')
    response_text = ""
    for resp in chatbot.query(query, stream=True):
        if resp != None:
            response_text += resp['token']

    response_text = response_text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
    
    return jsonify({"response": response_text})

That's the flask function, here's the javascript:
async function getResponse(message) {
    const responseText = await fetchResponse(message);
    appendMessage('assistant', responseText);
}

async function fetchResponse(message) {
    const response = await fetch('/chat', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: message })
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log('Raw Response:', data);
    return data.response.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, '');
}

I'm at a loss here, really. I've tried googling this and I can't find anything about it at all. Filtering either in the python or the javascript does nothing. Printing it out to the console in python or javascript also just gives me the expected text, none of the squares.

Please do not use (sole) images of code/data/errors in your [mcve]. Post response_text.encode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace') before decoding (hence, destroying) it as in your response_text = response_text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
